# Android EditText - Focus on it and select all text programmatically

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I am trying to figure out how do I focus on EditText and select all text in it.

Here is the scenario:

1. User enters user name in EditText
2. App evaluates it somehow and if user name is not valid, it should 
   automatically focus on User Name Edit text and select all text user has entered previously so user does not have to backspace to delete it all in order to reenter new user name.

Much appreciated,

Comment: Can we select a specific word programmatically? for example, sth like `select(start,end)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out.  Here is what I did.

I have a button user clicks when he enters user name (the positive button on DialogFragment).  On button click event, I do this:

```
editUserName.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
editUserName.selectAll();
```

This will focus and select all text in the EditText.

Comment: `editUserName.requestFocus();` instead of `selectAll()`.

Answer (score 13):

For **selection** of all the text of Edittext, you can use

`editText.setSelection(0,editText.getText().toString().length());`

and if you want to set **cursor position** you can use

`editText.setSelection(position);`

Comment: `toString()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` to the `EditText`