# Text selection depending on the phone

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my app, I have an EditText where the user can select a part of the text. The problem is that the selection behavior is different depending on the phone : with one, the user can select normally, but with another one the user must tap on the text indicator and then tap on "Select All".

How can I set the behavior like the first one as default ? And why the behavior is different between phones ?

Thank you for your answers, have a nice day !

**EDIT :**

Now I select the word which contains the cursor with this method :

```
fun EditText.selectCurrentWord() {
    val textSpan = text
    val selection = selectionStart
    val pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+")
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(textSpan)
    var start: Int
    var end: Int

    while (matcher.find()) {
        start = matcher.start()
        end = matcher.end()

        if (selection in start..end) {
            setSelection(start, end)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

But now the problem is that cursors at the start and end of selection doesn't appear...

The EditText is selectable and `isCursorVisible` is set to true.

Comment: As an alternative you can give a dedicated button to [select all text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31551639/7948109)

Comment: @RahulGaur Yes, but I have a multilines EditText, so I want to select only one part of the text...

Comment: You can modify this, if you want to select only the first line, you can find the position where `return` is

Comment: But how can I select the word where the user does a long click ?

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer on how to get cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6900610/7948109)

Comment: Yes thank you ! I can select the good word thanks to you, but cursors do not appear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a `Button` to select the text using

```
EditText myET = findViewById(R.id.myET);
Button selectBtn = findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);

selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myET.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        myET.selectAll();    
    }
});
```

You can open `context menu` using

```
openContextMenu(myET);
```

You can also get the position of starting and end point of cursor

```
myET.getSelectionStart();
myET.getSelectionEnd();
```

Referring answers

1. [Getting cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6900610/7948109)
2. [Select Text programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31551639/7948109)

### Update 1

Add this in your button click, this seems to work, but sometimes you have to click 2 times you can tweak this

```
myET.performLongClick();
myET.setSelection(0, myET.length());
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer ! I've tried to use ```openContextMenu``` but nothing happens... With the start/end points of cursor, can I show anchors ?

Comment: Thank you it's perfect ! I can even remove the ```postDelayed``` to just keep ```performLongClick``` and ```setSelection```